# Permissions to invoke UDT method in SQL/CLR

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I create a user-defined type in `SQL` Server from an assembly using `SQL/CLR`. I can invoke its method by `sa` but not by a public user.

**The error message is:**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: no permission to execute。

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalNextResult(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.NextResult()

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderSmi(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

in MyAssembly.MyType.Parse(SqlString param)
```

How to grant permissions to invoke method by public users?
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is your DB user is a member of db_owner role? Else

Try this,

In SQL Server Managment studio

Expand the DB -> Expand Security -> Expand Users

Then right click on the DB user whom you are using to connect -> Properties

Select "Securables" from the top right pane.

Add your object and give permissions you want from the bottom panel.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, but I only find 'User-defined Data Type' and 'User-defined Table Type', but my object is 'User-defined Type'. So I cannot solve this problem at the moment.

Comment: There is not EXECUTE permission for assembly, I tried REFERENCE, but does not work.

Comment: Probably you can try it doing through the code then Syntax: 

GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::[dbo].[YourType] to [DBUserAccount]

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this method but does not work. Now I found the solution: GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [the user]. (execute in master db)